# Appropriate analysis for Multiple Regression with two moderators

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, spss

I am having troubles figuring out if my assumptions for the appropriate SPPS tests are correct.

I am doing a secondary analysis from an existing SPSS file.

I have two independent variables (with Yes/No Answers), and two dependent variables.
I aim to do multiple regression analysis and also investigate if two other variables moderate the effect of my independent variable.

First I will do reliability analysis, reporting Cronbach's alpha. I have to do this for my independent variables and my moderator variables only, right? (the ones that are part of the Questionnaire).

Initially I was thinking of doing `SPSS -> Linear -> Multiple Regression`. Where in Block (1) I will input independent variables and dependent variables, and in Block(2) input the two moderator variables. Is that how I should approach my research analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the details here are unclear to me. Because you say "I have one two independent variables" it isn't 100% clear to me how many IVs you have. You also mention doing a reliability check on the IV(s), but you said they are binary, so you wouldn't test the reliability of a single yes/no question.

Going back to the overall modeling question, there's no need for the blocks. Put the interaction terms (IV * moderator) in the model and if the estimate is significant, then it is significant. If you are adding the "moderators" without an interaction term, you aren't testing moderation.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Initially the questions are not binary yes/no but in 4-point scale (I chose to dichotomise the variable and convert it to yes/no - not sure if that was an appropriate call). I have two independent variables (sorry about the error). So I am guessing that I have to do what you described for each of the IVs. Thank you

Comment: Is SPSS doing the interaction terms by default or I have to create a new variable with the product of variables ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In regression "moderation" is interaction. The usual way to test this is by including the products of the moderators and the IVs.

Comment: my assumptions are based on this : https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/dichotomous-moderator-analysis-using-spss-statistics.php , should I then move the moderators to the first block ? is this what you are describing? Thank you

Comment: It's not about assumptions and it's not about blocks.  It's about what "moderation" means.  You need to include the products of the variables.

Comment: Not statistical assumption .. I just used the tutorial as guidance. Not really sure what I should do differently from what they describe. Thank you for the response. As you described I want basically to see how the variables interact with my independent - dependent prediction.

Comment: You should do what I said to do - multiply the two variables.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I calculated the interaction terms variable1*variable2 and I added it as independent variables to see if the regression is significant. If the interaction is significant, should I do another test to see exactly the direction of the interaction or I can see it from the regression output ? (to see if with variable 2 enhances or decreases the effect on the dependant). Sorry if my question was a bit confusing.

Comment: The sign of the interaction coefficient is in the output.